# Resample function in python

Tags: python

I'd like to change the x-axis scale of a function. Imagine, I have `conv(x)` which performs the conversion from `x` to `s = conv(x)`. Now, I've got some function `f(x)` and I'd like to make it accept argument on the `s` scale.

The only way I see it done is to use a newton method (from scipy) to find `x` corresponding to some `s`:

```
from scipy.optimize import newton

def g(s):
    def zero(x):
        return conv(x) - s
    s = newton(zero, x0)
    return f(s)
```

This seems a bit convoluted and ugly. Is there a better way of doing such conversion?

EDIT: the relation between `x` and `s` is monotonic.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly - doesn't this require an inverse function for `conv`? You can convert x to s using `conv`, but your scenario requires conversion in the other direction.

Comment: This is what I'm asking about. I don't have an easy way of doing an inverse, apart from newton.

Comment: If there were an easy way to compute the inverse of an arbitrary function, cryptography wouldn't work. I suppose you could brute-force a walk through the domain of `conv` and cache the results, if the domain is small enough.

Comment: Well, maybe not easy way, but, say, more pythonic way ;)

Comment: It's not a question of what's pythonic, it's a question of what's computationally possible. Or even theoretically possible. A function maps input from its domain set to output from its range set; there is no way to reverse it without traversing the entire domain until you hit the matching range element. Or to use prior knowledge of the behavior of the function.

Comment: I have just shown that this is computationally possible. My example works. It is not always possible, of course... The conversion function is monotonic in this case. But I do see where you are going, and I do get it. I just thought there might be some numpy/scipy instrument which automatizes it in a pretty way...

Comment: You can compute a number of (s,x) points and interpolate, eg. by fitting a cubic spline.

Comment: If the conversion function is monotonic then I think my theory-based objections can be overcome. Some kind of modified binary search algorithm is probably what I'd use - keep adding increasing powers of two to `x` until `conv(x)` is greater than `s`, then search the range of `x0` and `x1` such that `conv(x0) < s < conv(x1)`. With memoization if `conv` is nontrivial to call. But the scipy method is likely faster, if it works for the functions in question.